# How to get ASCII output for ASCII input from a Serial Device (ttyUSBx)

Tags: linux, command-line, io, serial-port

Is there any way to get an ASCII output for an ASCII input (short string like "GET T").
I tried minicom but it does not work well.

**EXAMPLE:**

```
stty speed 9600 cs8 ...  
echo "GET T" > /dev/ttyUSBx
```

**OUTPUT:**

> /SOME/PLACE/WHERE/I/CAN/SEE/WHAT/HAPPENED.{TXT,LOG,...}

or straight LINE OUTPUT
NO X Solution. I need **classic command line**

I would prefer something like miniterm with SEND/GET STRING functionality

Thanks!

Comment: First case: install `com` from tinyserial package. Second: run `cat /dev/ttyUSBx` on next terminal.

Comment: Can you provide more details about what doesn't work for you in `minicom`?  That'll help provide relevant info about how to configure/use minicom.

Comment: Sorry for my very late answer! It's not that minicom does not work, I just want to solve it another way!

Comment: @Eddy_Em - where can i get the tinyserial package?

Comment: @dinesh - I want to run a cronjob checking a thermometer...

Comment: Here is another case of minicom not showing ASCII characters. Do you have any sugestions? http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/209472/uart-minicom-and-ascii